# A plugin to see what I'm doing in Vim

Tags: gvim, plugin

I'd like to see what I do when I'm navigating in Vim just as we could see on the following picture :

[image]

Could anyone be able to tell me how is it possible to do it? Is there exist a certain plugin for that?

Comment: I have no idea what that picture portrays, but maybe try vi.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @JeffSchaller The portray means that when I start to enter the command-line `da`, I can see what I'm doing, because of the "cloud".

Answer (score 5):

I believe the screenshot is referencing http://vim-adventures.com/.

The only assistance I can offer is to add the following to your .vimrc:

```
    set showcmd
```

This will show commands you issue in normal mode (like dd, dw, etc.), but it won't show things like the navigation keys (h, j, k, l).